# check event of panel in the main java class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to check the event of panel class which is being added on the `JFrame` class.  In this sample program there is a button on a panel.

I want to monitor the click event of the button from the source frame.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    test() {
        Container cp = this.getContentPane();
        JButton b1 = new JButton("add");
        cp.add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("add")) {
            panel1 frm = new panel1();
            cp.add(frm);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test t1 = new test();
        t1.show(true);
    } 
}


class panel1 extends JPanel {
    panel1() {
        JButton b1 = new JButton("ok");
        add(b1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue with existing code?

Comment: when i click on the ok button on jpanel  , i should be able to check this event in jframe class

Comment: `test` and `panel1` should be `Test` and `Panel1` when you declare a new class

Comment: is `Panel1` inner class of `Test` or you want implement it separate?

Comment: make reference of Container outside of Constructor to access it in actionPerformed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `JButton` available to the "out side" world some how.

I, personally, would be reluctant to make the button itself available, instead, I would allow the outside world the ability to to attach a `ActionListener` to it...

```
public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public Test() {
        Container cp = this.getContentPane();
        JButton b1 = new JButton("add");
        cp.add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("add")) {
            TestPane frm = new TestPane();
            frm.addActionListener(...); // Add your new action listener here
            cp.add(frm);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test t1 = new test();
        t1.show(true);
    } 
}


public class TestPane extends JPanel {
    private JButton b1;
    public TestPane() {
        b1 = new JButton("ok");
        add(b1);
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        b1.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        b1.removeActionListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever you put in frame it just put into the center of the frame. So use BorderLayout for this to be visible as below

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("add")) {
            System.out.println("in actionPerformed");
            panel1 frm = new panel1();
          // this.removeAll();
            add(frm,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.validate();
        }
    }
```